# Loop through labels and change values c#

Tags: c#, winforms, loops

I am looking to update some label text from an XML document.

The labels are named `supName1`, `supName2` etc.

I have a for loop which runs through for all the XML nodes in  List.Count.

```
var n = list.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

I need to update the label text for each of the list.count but I can't figure out how to reference the labels.

From my VBA experience it would be something like `"supName"+i` but I can't figure it out for C#.

I've tried the following;

```
var label = (Label)Controls["supName" + i];
```

but it is returning null when trying to use it as follows;

```
label.Text = list[i].Attributes["name"].Value;
```

Comment: Use [Control.ControlCollection.Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28VS.80%29.aspx), e.g. `this.Controls.Find($"supName{i}", true) as Label;`

Comment: Is this windows forms, wpf or some other UI framework? please use the appropriate tag.

Comment: Windows Forms - tagged as winforms on initial post. Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the labels in your form by their `Name` property, but have to keep in mind that they may be placed on a child control, not the form itself. The method that helps you here is [`ControlCollection.Find()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find(v=vs.110).aspx) that you can call on your form's `Controls` property which represents the form's `ControlCollection`:

```
int n = list.Count;
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    // the second argument "true" indicates to 
    // search child controls recursivly
    Label label = Controls.Find($"supName{i}", true).OfType<Label>().FirstOrDefault(); 
    if (label == null) continue; // no such label, add error handling
    label.Text = list[i].Attributes["name"].Value;
}
```

Comment: I am using WinForms yes. Getting an error with the Controls.Find. It says it can't convert Windows.Forms.Control[] to Windows.Form.Label

Comment: @AdrianBrown yes sorry, fixed it in my answer. `Find()` returns an array of matching items. But normally it's not so easy to have two controls with the same name in one form. My solution now takes the first control with that name that is a `Label`.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it...

```
foreach (Label myControl in this.Controls
                 .OfType<Label>()
                 .Where(myControl => (myControl).Name == "ValueFromList"))
            {
                //Apply change here.
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason this did not work:

```
var label = (Label)Controls["supName" + i];
```

Is because controls are hierarchical, and your label is probably not a direct descendant of the current Form/Control.

For this purpose there exists a [`Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28VS.80%29.aspx) method:

```
var label = (Label)ControlsCollection.Find("supName" + i,true);
```

Answer (score 1):

These `Label`s are reference types so you can use one line `Linq` for that :

```
Controls.OfType<Label>().Select(lbl => lbl.Text = "hello world!");
```

If you need to change specific `Label` then do :

```
Controls.OfType<Label>().Where(lbl => lbl.Name.EndsWith(index)).Select(lbl => lbl.Text = "hello world!");
// where index -> int index;
```

So basically to find `Label` you want use :

```
Controls.OfType<Label>().Where(lbl => lbl.Name.EndsWith(index));
// or if you want only first matched element 
Controls.OfType<Label>().FirstOrDefault(lbl => lbl.Name.EndsWith(index));
```

Answer (score 1):

Following code should do atleast for windows form application. thanks

```
       var labels = this.Controls.OfType<Label>();
            if (labels != null)
            {
                int cnt = 0;
                foreach (var label in labels)
                {
                    label.Text = "New label text " + cnt++;
                }
            }
```